# FS alternative for react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docx

I am trying to use the docx.js library to generate a docx file with an image loaded from file.

In the official docs linked bellow they use the FS library to load the image from path but this library is not supported by react. Is there any other way I can load a image file ? Thanks

https://docx.js.org/#/usage/images

Answer (score 0):

You can use an image's Base64 representation or an external image url while generating your document in React.

```js
import {Document} from 'docx'
const imageBase64Data = `someBase64 representation of an image`

const Component = () => {
  ...
  function generateFromBase64() {
    const doc = new Document();
    const image1 = Media.addImage(
      doc,
      Uint8Array.from(atob(imageBase64Data), c => c.charCodeAt(0))
    );
    ...
  }
  
  async function generateFromUrl() {
    const doc = new Document();
    const blob = await fetch(
      "https://i.picsum.photos/id/972/200/200.jpg"
    ).then(r => r.blob());

    const image1 = Media.addImage(doc, blob);
    ...
  }
}
```

This is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-qdqu7z) from the package itself.

Comment: appreciate the reply but what about loading an image from drive?